# Excel 2016: How to create a pivot table and line chart where I can select each month using a slicer

Tags: excel, date, charts, pivot, slicers

I have a very large spreadsheet with a lot of financial data broken down into type of expense in each month of the FY. I'm trying to create multiple pivot tables and charts with a single slicer named "Month" connected to all the charts in a dashboard so in theory I can select "July" and every teams individual line graph should change to show their expense in that month however my data looks like this and I can't find away to properly manipulate the data in a pivot...help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would just use index() with match() to get the relevant value for each team,  then plot those values. A dropdown to select the month would be good.

Comment: "I would just use index() with match() to get the relevant value for each team, then plot those values" could you elaborate please?
I assume you meant place the months in the filter area? Unfortunately a dropdown filter only shows the costs as a choice option, it doesn't help with my dashboard slicers. I want to present my data by selecting the month in a Slicer which interactively change multiple line charts

Comment: I would do it on a worksheet without slicers or powerpivot etc etc I would show you a simple example but you gave images not data so I won't be typing it.

Comment: I'm not sure how index and match would help during a presentation. I can't sit at a terminal to type a month in a cell to give an output cost. I need to simply touch the chosen month on a display screen to visually show the costs

Comment: As I said: a DROPDOWN to choose the month... aka data validation

Comment: I finally got there using a drop down for each Team, it's untidy but it works to a certain level. I used the formula

=INDEX(D3:J11,MATCH(K16,B3:B11,0),1)

(it wont let me attach an image)

Comment: My issue now is how manipulate it to show the different Expenses by Teams by selecting a drop down for the Months

Comment: So set up a dropdown that has the  items it displays set by the team that is chosen. choose90 comes in handy...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to select the Team, my original table has hundreds of rows of info split amongst many teams which is why I need to select Months to compare the teams financial performances. For some reason INDEX MATCH will only show the cells in columns, I've changed the dropdown to select from the Months array and sure enough it will show the teams first months (Apr) correct figures but as soon as I select May the figures displayed move down the column of Apr, not shifting to the right to display May's figures. My working formula: =INDEX(D3:J11,MATCH(T2,D2:J2,0),1).

Comment: Actually don't worry about it. I appear to have found the limits of Excel. It can't do what I need so I'm looking at other ways to display my data, perhaps breaking it down into many sizeable chunks and having multiple dashboards. Thank you for your help, I have learnt something new with INDEX MATCH : )